# What is the correct way to change constraint constants

Tags: objective-c, ios-autolayout

I have to alter constraint but by changing constraint constants,
I get duplicates - Xcode gives a warning.

I can see that one constraint is the old one and the other is the new one,
and their memory addresses are different.

*What is the correct way to create and setup views to handle constraint changes?*

I my example I have a mainView which added to self.view, the provided view
when you extend UIViewController. "self.view" is provided and has no constraints set.

Main MainView is my container and I want to adjust its height to be above the keyboard whenever the keyboard appears.

**viewDidLoad:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

   [super viewDidLoad];

   _mainView = [UIView new];
   _mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
   [self.view addSubview:_mainView];
}
```

**viewWillLayoutSubviews:**

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {

 [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

 //moved to viewDidLoad
 //self.mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

//top
[[self view] addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_mainView
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                           toItem:self.view
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                       multiplier:1.0
                                                         constant:0]];

//bottom
_mainBottomContraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_mainView
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:self.view
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                     constant:_keyboardOffset];

[[self view] addConstraint:_mainBottomContraint];

//left
[[self view] addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_mainView
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                           toItem:self.view
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                       multiplier:1.0
                                                         constant:0]];

//right
[[self view] addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_mainView
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                           toItem:self.view
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                       multiplier:1.0
                                                         constant:0]];
```

-

Whenever I alter a constraint constant I get duplicate constraints,
viewWillLayoutSubviews gets called again and recreates the constraints.
How does one change the constraints without re-creation? Or what is the correct pattern to use here.

**keyboardWillShow - changes the constraint (setConstant)**

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)aNotification {

    if (![_chatTextField isFirstResponder]) {
        return;
    }

    CGSize tabBarSize = [[[self tabBarController] tabBar] bounds].size;    
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

    NSTimeInterval duration = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    UIViewAnimationCurve curve = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue];

    CGSize kbSize = [info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    CGRect bkgndRect = _mainView.frame;
    bkgndRect.size.height -= kbSize.height-tabBarSize.height;

    //animate with keyboard
    _keyboardOffset = -kbSize.height-tabBarSize.height;
    [_mainBottomContraint setConstant:_keyboardOffset];
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | curve     animations:^{
        [_mainView layoutIfNeeded];

    } completion:nil];
}
```

**LOGS**

Constraint 1 at memory address *0x174286450*

Constraint 2 at memory address *0x174288660*

```
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174286450 UIView:0x14fd5e5b0.bottom == UIView:0x14fe5edd0.bottom - 271   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174288660 UIView:0x14fd5e5b0.bottom == UIView:0x14fe5edd0.bottom   (active)>"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinions，you add the _mainBottomContraint twice.First,you creat a _mainBottomContraint and retain it,when the keyboard change,the _mainBottomContraint.constaints changes,and if the view in self.view.subviews change the frame,the system will post a notification,and the viewcontroller will recieve it,and call viewWillLayoutSubviews,like the view will call layoutSubviews.So you creat a _mainBottomContraint,so now,there are two bottomContraint and you get a warning.
You should add the contraints only once,you can add them in viewDidLoad function,and it will be good.

Comment: Thanks Zacks. Moving my constraints initialization to the viewDidLoad fixes the bug. But I am wondering what the correct pattern is. 

What do you put inside "viewWillLayoutSubviews" - Apple doc says "....When a view's bounds change, the view adjusts the position of its subviews....".

So I am changing the "bounds" using auto-layout. Does this method ever have a use when using auto layout?

Still seeking the goto pattern for creating views and laying them out.

Comment: agree. only create them once. viedDidLoad is best place for. To update only change constants (which you can animate)

Comment: following both answers will fix it. both is necessary. i never needed to overwrite the method viewWillLayoutSubviews. create your view with all constraints once. before adding it make sure to call translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints.

Comment: you can read the guides from apple.https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/DefiningYourSubclass.html.In the Managing view Layout,there is "UIKit notifies you at several points so that you can perform additional layout-related tasks",so you should update your constraints additional,instead of creating all constraits.

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

on the subView BEFORE adding it to another view. Otherwise some constraints get created automatically leading to warnings.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
[super viewDidLoad]; _mainView = [UIView new]; 
self.mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; 

[self.view addSubview:_mainView]; 
}
```

Then save references of your created constraints (like you do) and change them whenever neccesary.

Comment: I am still getting duplicates, I have updated my viewDidLoad, to do the masks into constraints off before adding them as you have mentioned.

I will update my question with logs.